# Setting up Angular 4 with ASP.NET MVC (.NET Framework) along with Webpack

Tags: .net, angular, model-view-controller

I have a requirement to setup an .NET MVC project along with Angular 4 and webpack. Can anyone give a step by step solution.

Comment: https://aspnetzero.com/Documents/Getting-Started-Angular this might be what your looking for, its not free but its exactly what you describe

Answer (score 0):

We recommend to create two separate applications as:

1. Server App: .NET WebAPI
2. Browser App: Angular4 SPA

You can use ng-cli tool which will generate the scaffolding template with application structure and then you can build the client side web app according to your requirements. ng-cli tool itself includes webpack and you do not needed to configure it separately, it will save your lots of time.

The browser app will communicate to the server via WebAPIs and you can authenticate APIs using Json Web Tokens.